# How to have multiple variables inside a blit() function

Tags: python, pygame

I would like to know if there is a way to do something like...

```
Characternumber = random.randint(1, 2)
Character1 = pygame.image.load("Character1.png")
Character2 = pygame.image.load("Character2.png")
screen.blit(Character[Characternumber], (0, 0))
```

Where I can use the blit() code for both characters.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to blit both characters you need to call `blit` twice. If you want to `blit` a random character, you have to put the characters in a list. However, list indices start at 0:

```py
Characternumber = random.randint(0, 1)
Character1 = pygame.image.load("Character1.png")
Character2 = pygame.image.load("Character2.png")
Character = [Character1, Character2]
screen.blit(Character[Characternumber], (0, 0))
```

To choose a random element from e list you can also use [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html):

```py
character_list = [
    pygame.image.load("Character1.png")
    pygame.image.load("Character2.png")
]
character = random.choice(character_list)
screen.blit(character, (0, 0))
```

Comment: Is there a code to check which character got chosen?

Comment: @Raifa ? You know the value of `Characternumber`, isn't it? Or you can use `no = character_list.index(character)`

Comment: Right. I want to have several characters on screen, and they all use the same .png file. I also want it so it detects which character dies e.g.character1, so I can spawn it back. Sorry for the rough explanation.

Comment: @Raifa This is a new question. The comment section is not intended to ask follow up questions. If you have a new question, [Ask a public question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).